# How to get all the values which are comma separated against one value of a table in vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I have one table in vertica. Table name sub_temp. Mapping key is an identity column.Data is as follows:

```
 MAPPING_KEY | SUBSCRIBER_KEY | DATASOCCODE
-------------+----------------+-------------
           1 |              1 | 123
           2 |              1 | 456
      250001 |              1 | 342
           3 |              2 | 789
           4 |              2 | 000
      250002 |              2 | 42
```

I want the output as below :

```
SUBSCRIBER_KEY | DATASOCCODE
---------------+-------------
             1 | 123,456,342
             2 | 789,000,42
```

There can be multiple DATASOCCODE against one SUBSCRIBER_KEY . Above data is just one instance.
Please suggest the approach for the above problem.

Comment: DATASOCCODE is int OR varchar

Comment: You may also want to check out the [`TRANSPOSE` extension](https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/compatlib_functions)